# ssh + ksh + grep + wc

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting

I'm trying to "ping" if some applications are running in some remote machines.

To do that I have a file with the servers and applications, like:

```
server1:application1
server2:application1
server3:application2
Etc.
```

I expect to obtain the number of applications with this name that are running in the server.

To connect and to check I need a ssh connection.

My script is a bash and is like this:

```
Ping_Applications () {    
    SetParam
    cat $APPFILE | while read next
    do
     server=`echo $next | cut -d : -f1`
     app=`echo $next | awk -F":" '{print $2}'`

     commando="/bin/ssh $server '/bin/ps -fea | /bin/grep $app | /bin/grep -v grep | /bin/wc -l'"
     eval COMA=\$\($commando\)
     echo $commando

     if [ $COMA != 0 ]
     then
      echo -e "$TIME : Application $app of on server $server is \E[32m[ RUNNING ]\E[0m";
     else
      echo -e "$TIME : Application $app of on server $server is \E[31m[ NOT RUNNING ]\E[0m";
     fi
    done;  
}
```

My problem is that when I send

```
ssh $server 'ps -fea | grep $app | grep -v grep | wc -l'
```

This returns the number, but when is sent by using the script, I have not answer, because (I think) the pipe open a new shell.

I don't know how to solve this.

Any idea?

Thanks

Luis

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Use the `{}` tool at the top-left of the edit box on highlighted code/data/error msgs to keep the correct formatting. Good luck!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just running the command directly instead of putting it in a string to `eval`?  Also, not related but you could try using `pgrep` instead of `ps` and 2 `grep`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Bash FAQ 50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

You want to put the command in an array, and not use `eval` to invoke it:

```
commando=( /bin/ssh $server '/bin/ps -fea | /bin/grep "'"$app"'" | /bin/grep -v grep | /bin/wc -l' )
COMA=$( "${commando[@]}" )
```

`commando` is an array with 3 elements, so the last element can be passed to the remote server as a single word. Note the careful quoting around `$app`

Also, since $COMA will be a number, use numeric comparison: `if [ $COMA -ne 0 ]`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to separate the /bin/ssh command and its arguments. Also put the "commando" in double quotes:

Instead of:

```
commando="/bin/ssh $server '/bin/ps -fea | /bin/grep $app | /bin/grep -v grep | /bin/wc -l'"
eval COMA=\$\($commando\)
```

Try this:

```
commando="/bin/ps -fea | /bin/grep $app ..."
/bin/ssh $server "$commando"
```

Bash variables gets expanded in double quotes, but not in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help

I mixed the answers from Eric Renouf and Glenn Jackman and the solution es like this:

```
Ping_Applications () {    
SetParam
cat $APPFILE | while read next
do
 server=`echo $next | cut -d : -f1`
 app=`echo $next | awk -F":" '{print $2}'`

 commando=( /bin/ssh $server '/bin/pgrep -f "'"$app"'" | /bin/wc -l' )
 COMA=$( "${commando[@]}" )

 if [ $COMA -gt 0 ]
 then
  echo -e "$TIME : Application $app of on server $server is \E[32m[ RUNNING ]\E[0m";
 else
  echo -e "$TIME : Application $app of on server $server is \E[31m[ NOT RUNNING ]\E[0m";
 fi
done;
```

}

Now i have a different problem:

This solution works, but only for the first input, then the script stops.

I have around 10 different applications in my $APPFILE, but only the first one is executed.

Regards.

Luis